# Post html form with file input fileds

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I Have **HTML** form with some text input and file input. I want to submit form using **jquery** form plugin and it is working ok, but the problem is when I select no file in file input, the file input field become part of `$_POST` with empty value I don't want it in `$_POST` array.

Please help.

This is My Code I am using CodeIgniter -  @Let's Code

```
public function saveDataSourceAttributesValues() {
    $data_source_id = $this->input->post('data_source_id');
    $attributes_values_row_id = $this->input->post('row_id');
    $text_attributes = $this->input->post(); // Text Input fields
    $images_attributes = $_FILES; // Files Input field

    if ($attributes_values_row_id == '') {
        $last_row_id = $this->DataSourceModel->getDataSourceAttributesValuesLastRowId($data_source_id);
        if ($last_row_id) {
            $row_id = (int) $last_row_id + 1;
        } else {
            $row_id = 1;
        }
    } else {
        //Edit case
        $row_id = $attributes_values_row_id;
    }

    if (!empty($text_attributes)) {
        foreach ($text_attributes as $attribute_id => $value) {
            if (is_numeric($attribute_id)) {
                $temp_data = array(
                    'data_source_id' => $data_source_id,
                    'data_source_attribute_id' => $attribute_id,
                    'value' => $value,
                    'row_id' => $row_id,
                    'created' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
                );

                if ($attributes_values_row_id == '') {
                    $this->CommonModel->insert('data_source_attribute_value', $temp_data);
                } else {
                    $this->DataSourceModel->updateDataSourceAttributeValue($attribute_id, $row_id, $temp_data);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (!empty($images_attributes)) {

        $this->load->library('upload');
        $config['upload_path'] = './data_sources/images/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = '*';
        $config['max_size'] = '10000';
        //$config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
        //$config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;

        foreach ($images_attributes as $attribute_id => $value) {
            if (is_numeric($attribute_id)) {
                $config['file_name'] = str_replace(' ', '_', $_FILES[$attribute_id]['name']);
                $image_path = $config['upload_path'] . '/' . $config['file_name'];
                $this->upload->initialize($config);
                if ($this->upload->do_upload($attribute_id)) {
                    $temp_data = array(
                        'data_source_id' => $data_source_id,
                        'data_source_attribute_id' => $attribute_id,
                        'value' => $image_path,
                        'row_id' => $row_id,
                        'created' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
                    );

                    if ($attributes_values_row_id == '') {
                        $this->CommonModel->insert('data_source_attribute_value', $temp_data);
                    } else {
                        $this->DataSourceModel->updateDataSourceAttributeValue($attribute_id, $row_id, $temp_data);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    $response['response'] = 200;
    $response['message'] = 'Data source attributes values has been saved successfully.';
    $response['error'] = '';
    $response['data'] = '';
}
```

Comment: Do you have `isset` in your code?

Comment: show some code We will be able to understand your problem better then

Answer (score 1):

Any files uploaded will be in the $_FILES array. You can find all the information that you need in the php manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: You right, But the problem is when I select no file it become part of $_POST array with empty value

Comment: See @Manish answer for a possible solution

Answer (score 1):

You get `$_POST` values array and a quick way to remove **empty elements** from an array is using `array_filter` without a callback function. This will also remove **0s** (zeroes) though.

```
$myArray = array_filter( $_POST );
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need not to have this field in $_POST? You should just ignore it on the server if it is empty.

If there is any reason, you can try to remove the  element from DOM before sending form. (http://api.jquery.com/remove/).

Answer (score 0):

how about checking it before posting whether input file exist or not, if not then remove that tag and then post.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I created one php file which uploads the image. It might be helpful to you. I am uploading an image and saving it into database image with its name.

here is index.php

```
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <form action="get.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <p>
    <label for="image">Upload an image</label>
    <input type="file" name="image" id="image" />

    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
    </p>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

here is get.php

```
        <?php

            //connect to database
            mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
            mysql_select_db("photo") or die(mysql_error());

            //file properties


            $file = $_FILES['image'];//['tmp_name'];

            if (!isset($file))
            echo "Please select an image.";
            else
            {

            $image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
            $image_name = addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
            $image_size = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

                if ($image_size==FALSE)
            echo "That's not an image.";
            else
            {
            if (!$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO store VALUES('','$image_name','$image')"))
            echo "Problem uploading image.";
            else
            {
            $lastid = mysql_insert_id();
            echo "image uploaded. "; 

            }
            }
            }
            ?>
```

structure of store table of photo database is on [this link](http://www.dreamsofaurangabad.com/demo3.html):